# $this object not working properly when used in services in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection, controller, symfony-2.3

I've working for a while with Symfony and I started to use controllers as services. The problem is that I'm not sure if I get how the Dependency Injection works. If I print $this inside an action it works perfectly.

```
/**
 * @Route("/testing/this")
 */
public function thisAction(Request $request)
{
    var_dump($this);
    return new Response();
}
```

Response:

```
object(Linkedip\WizardBundle\Controller\PaymentsController)[153]
  protected 'object' => null
  protected 'container' => 
    object(appDevDebugProjectContainer)[198]
      protected 'parameterBag' => 
        object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\FrozenParameterBag)[48]
          protected 'parameters' => 
            array
              ...
```

But then, I decided to make my controller a service to be used in other controllers (I want to have actions methods and service methods in one controller).

```
parameters:
linkedip.controller.payments.class: Linkedip\WizardBundle\Controller\PaymentsController

services:
    payments.controller:
        class:  %linkedip.controller.payments.class%
```

So, I add a new method that I'll plan to use in other controllers but when I try to call $this inside the new method look what I get.

```
/**
 * @Route("/testing/this")
 */
public function thisAction(Request $request)
{
    $paymentsController = $this->get('payments.controller');
    $paymentsController->service();
    return new Response();
}


/**
 *  [SERVICE]
 */
public function service()
{
    var_dump($this);
    return null;
}
```

Response:

```
object(Linkedip\WizardBundle\Controller\PaymentsController)[937]
      protected 'object' => null
      protected 'container' => null
```

To solve this issue I created a setter to inject $this object directly to the controller.

```
/**
 *  [DEPENDENCY INJECTION]
 */
protected $object;
public function setObject($object) { $this->object = $object; }
```

And then, When I try to call one of those services I need to add an extra line setting $this.

```
$paymentsController = $this->get('payments.controller');
$paymentsController->setObject($this);
```

And in the service method, I call the object.

```
$em = $this->object->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

This code works for me but I feel is a dirty trick. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> [..]But then, I decided to make my controller a service to be used in other controllers (I want to have actions methods and service methods in one controller).

I don't agree with this architecture choice. You should make your own controller to let the other ones herits from it. Then, if you still need a service, you can create one.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But I still don't know how to fix the issue.

Comment: Do I know how to call a form from the repository? no, because it's not where it belongs. It's the same kind of problem here, that's why I can't help you more than my answer sorry

Answer (score 0):

I agree with goto, you should not mix responsibilities within one class. Also, this is mainly the cause for your problem. To answer your question:

By defining your controller as a service, you are not using the default instantiation logic for a controller, so the container will not be injected automatically. If you want this to happen, you should manually inject the container (or better: the specific services you need) from within your dependency injection config. But, again, if you plan on still using the controller in the 'regular' way, by defining routes for example, things will get REALLY messy,  so I would suggest, if you are already playing with the DIC, just create a separate service and call that from within your other controller. Hope this helps.